# Laravel form selected as filter

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to find documentation to do something I find a bit tricky. I'm trying to make a drop-down menu to be a filter that updates my index coming from a database.

This is my mockup [image]

So basically I want that when I change the filter from the dropdown menu, the list of projects update with the ones only have the good filter from a database column.

I hope I'm clear. Thank you !

Comment: you should use either ajax/re-submit the form to query the results based on your selected filter. Or use jquery dataTable to filter on client side.

Comment: you want a hot coffee, burger with the answer too sir?

Comment: I didn't ask for a complete HOW-TO to do that. Just wanted some tips and maybe some tutorial you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use jQuery [dataTables](https://datatables.net/). On each `change()` option of that dropdown, update the results with AJAX. Since you didn't provide your code, I cannot help but adding the how-to link. More info: [here](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html).